# SearchAPI and Hibernate unexpected end of subtree

Tags: java, hibernate, google-search-api

I've the following entity

```
@Entity
public class Task {

private List<TaskParameter> taskParameters = Collections.emptyList();

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "taskParameters", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
            name = "task_id"))
    public List<TaskParameter> getTaskParameters() {
        return taskParameters;
    }

}
```

and the TaskParameter entity is an embeddable defined below:

```
@Embeddable
public class TaskParameter {
        private String name;
    private String value;

}
```

I'm using Search API this method

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true) 
public List<Task> getTaskByRequisitionId(String requisitionId) {
    List<Task> tasks;
    Search search = new Search();
    search.addFilterAll("taskParameters",Filter.equal("value", requisitionId));
    tasks = taskDao.search(search);
    return tasks;
}
```

but get exception

```
[INFO] 2013-02-28 10:20:06,641 [btpool0-14] ERROR org.hibernate.hql.PARSER - <AST>:0:0: unexpected end of subtree
[INFO] 2013-02-28 10:20:06,642 [btpool0-14] ERROR org.hibernate.hql.PARSER - <AST>:0:0: expecting "from", found '<ASTNULL>'

[INFO] org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree [select _it from com.planetsystems.procnet.model.jbpm.Task _it where not exists (from _it.taskParameters _it1 where not (_it1.value = :p1 and _it1.value is not null))]
```

I'm using genericdao 1.1.0, and hibernate 3.5.6-Final

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is probably that the genericdao framework is not able handle the @ElementCollection case. I didn't think of this case before. Thanks for bringing it up. Perhaps I can add it to the framework in a future release.

In the mean time, write your method to use native Hibernate querying. You can get the Hibernate session directly in your DAO using getSession(). When you get it working, please update this thread with the HQL query that were able to get working. I can use that to figure out a way to build the capability into the framework.

Thanks.